# Executing Runnables in Future

Tags: java, android

Let's assume that I have an Activity that has methods which require JNI library to work. JNI library is loaded at runtime, so there is a chance that we can get exception( after restarting application for instance) in Activity's onCreate(), onResume() because library is not yet loaded. So, I've been thinking - what if I send the code wrapped in Runnable in some class with list of runnables to be executed, and the class will receive event that libraries(or any other event) were loaded and thus will execute the Runnables when it's possible. I'm trying to achieve this using EventBus, but there is always an exception:

> E/Event: Could not dispatch event: class
>   com.vc.intent.EventAppStateChanged to subscribing class class
>   com.vc.model.FutureExecutor

But these exceptions doesn't tell me much. How can I find out where exactly did the code break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the idea itself is not bad, it was just my stupid brain xD. EventBust wasn't showing what caused the exception so I've simpy put the code in try-catch:

```
public void onEventMainThread(EventAppStateChanged event) {
        if (event.isState(AppState.NORMAL)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "EventAppStateChanged (to NORMAL) received");
            try {
                for (Runnable runnable : toBeExecutedList) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "FutureExecutor executing Runnable: " + runnable);
                    VCEngine.getHandler().postDelayed(runnable, 10);
                    toBeExecutedList.remove(runnable);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "FutureExecutor exception: ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And I found out that I remove an element of a list inside for loop. This can be solved by using iterator or simply clearing the list after for loop. And now it works.